# update an object inside couchbase document using CBQ console

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a document like below

```
{
    "runs": {
        "run1": {
            "result": "pass",
            "state": "success"
        },
        "run2": {
            "result": "fail",
            "state": "incomplete"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add an object to "runs". object is like below using cbq query?

```
"run3": {
    "result": "pass",
    "state": "complete"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try an [`UPDATE ... SET ...`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html) N1QL query?

I ran this query:

```
UPDATE naveen
SET runs.run3 = { "result": "pass", "state" : "complete" }
WHERE META().id = 'doc1';
```

And the end result document is:

```
{
  "runs": {
    "run1": {
      "result": "pass",
      "state": "success"
    },
    "run2": {
      "result": "fail",
      "state": "incomplete"
    },
    "run3": {
      "result": "pass",
      "state": "complete"
    }
  }
}
```